# Compile and run code in nested folders

Tags: c, shell, jar

I am running Ubuntu. I have a folder "Project", and in that folder I have a bunch of sub-folders. In each of the sub-folders I have either a .c file, a .jar file or a .py file. I want to iterate over all the files, and for each file, compile it, and run 5 times with different input it using the "time" command to time the execution time.

I want to create a shell script for this, but I can't seem to find a good way to recurse over all the files in the sub-folders.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If all of the subfolders are the same depth you can use `for i in ./*/*/*/*.py` with the appropriate number of *'s.  Use one loop for each format since the actions will be different anyways.

Comment: If I try

for i in ./*.py
do
 echo "$i"
done

I get the output ./*.py

Comment: I missed a level so using ./*/*.py fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bash4 you can set `globstar` to recurse all subdirs without caring about depth

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar

for file in /path/to/your/files/**; do

case "${file##.*}" in
c)
   gcc -c "$file"
   ;;
jar)
   java -jar "$file"
   ;;
py)
   python "$file"
   ;;
esac
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like:

```
for folder in *
do
  if [ -d $folder] then
    cd $folder
    for file in *.py
    do
      if [ -f $file ] then
        do your stuff ..
      fi
    done
    for file in *.c
    do
      if [ -f $file ] then
      fi
    done
    .......
    cd ..
  fi
done
```